# Add multiple coordinates to a d3 line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3 JS 6.2.0, I want a simple way to access the beginning and end points of a line. The line should have multiple points to it:

[image]

When I try to add multiple x, y points, the additional points do not render:

```
var line = svg
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 50)
    .attr("y2", 85)
    .attr("x3", 100)
    .attr("y3", 200)
    .attr("x4", 200)
    .attr("y4", 275)
    .attr("stroke-width", 10)
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

I wanted to use `line` rather than `path` because:

- I need to be able to drag the line
- I need to be able to access the starting coordinates `x1, y1` and ending coordinates `x4, y4` with ease.

`Path` doesn't seem easy to do that with.

---

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

svg [`line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line)s only take two pairs of coordinates. The traditional way of doing a multipoint line in d3 is by using a [`path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path). [`polyline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polyline) is also a possibility, though I don't think d3 has convenience functions for those, and you'll probably run into any of the same issues with path. To use paths with d3, you can use d3.line() as a helper function.

Here's a snippet:

```js
var lineHelper = d3.line().x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y);
var data = [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 60, y: 85 },
  { x: 100, y: 200 },
  { x: 200, y: 275 }
];
var line = d3.select('svg')
  .append('path')
  .datum(data)
  .attr('d', lineHelper)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

From here, if you want to access/set the beginning or end coordinates, you can use `data[0].x` or `y`; or `data[data.length-1].x` or `y`.

If you need to rerender the line (if you change data, say), you can just call:

`line.attr('d', lineHelper);`

#### Moving the line

```js
var lineHelper = d3.line().x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y);
var data = [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 60, y: 85 },
  { x: 100, y: 200 },
  { x: 200, y: 275 }
];
var line = d3.select('svg')
  .append('path')
  .datum(data)
  .attr('d', lineHelper)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', '4px');
var circles = d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data([data[0], data[data.length - 1]])
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 8);
circles.attr('cx', d=>d.x).attr('cy', d=>d.y);
  
line.call(d3.drag().on('drag', dragged).on('end', end));

function end() {
  // do something with the data
  console.log(data[0].x, data[0].y, data[data.length-1].x, data[data.length-1].y);
}
function dragged(event) {
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.x += event.dx;
    d.y += event.dy;
  });
  line.attr('d', lineHelper);
  // rebind the first and last data points, just in case if the objects in data changed
  circles.data([data[0], data[data.length - 1]])
    .attr('cx', d=>d.x)
    .attr('cy', d=>d.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<svg width=600 height=300></svg>
```

Comment: thanks. so if I wanted to be able to drag this line and get the updated beginning line point and end line point coordinates, how would I do that?

Comment: If you're talking about just points, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723245/) as a reference, though to run it using d3 version 6, you'd need to change `function dragged(d)` to `function dragged(event, d)` and change the enclosed references of `d3.event` to just `event`.

Comment: If you're talking about moving the line, you can see the edit to the post

Comment: thanks so much for this. Last question: do you know how to make the point at `data[0]`  and point at `data[data.length - 1]` larger so it looks like a larger point on the line? See above edit for example. For example, I want to do `data[0].style('stroke-width', '10px')` but `data[0]` is not a style-able object.

Comment: I don't think you can get those with just styling. You'd probably need to do something like add circles to those points. See the revised post.